# guess the secret text inside a jpg file using outguess in linux

Tags: linux, jpeg, steganography

How can I get the secret content of a jpg file using outguess command without knowing the passphrase ? Before all is it possible to do so, guessing the content using outguess in linux without knowing the passphrase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outguess encrypts the content using AES prior to encoding using the passphrase.

Brute force is the only realistic method of breaking AES, and so you would need to use something like `stegbreak` to iterate through passwords or dictionary words and employ a lot of patience.